# Couldn't "A truck has parked in the driveway." be correct because the truck could be self-driving these days?

Tags: meaning-in-context, active-vs-passive

[image: Screenshot if a Grammarly suggestion]

Above is an screenshot of a suggestion made by Grammarly in the sentence.

It says:

> The word **has** doesn’t seem to fit this context.
>   Consider replacing it with a different one.

For this sentence:

> A truck **has parked** in the driveway.

---

The above sentence seems wrong at first, as also claimed by [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/), but think about it; what if the truck was meant to be a self-driving one?

**Edit:** Would including *itself* be necessary in that case as follows?

> A truck **has parked** *itself* in the driveway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to use a part to mean a whole or vice versa, and there is nothing wrong with this so long as there is no ambiguity. Now we have self driving trucks there could possibly be ambiguity, although they are not yet so common that it would be to necessary the use of the word "itself" in most contexts.